# Extracting vertices from fbx model using XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, extract, vertices, fbx

I am attempting to iterate through the vertices of an FBX model using C# and XNA 4.0.  I think that if I can get access to the vertices, then I'll be able to access the other parts such as  face normals, edges, `PolygonVertexIndex`, etc. on my own.

I found an article by Jon Watte discussing how to do this using XNA 3.0,
[Extracting Vertices and Triangles from an XNA Model](http://www.enchantedage.com/vertices-and-bounding-box-from-model-and-vertex-buffer-in-xna-framework)
but the 3.0 structure that he used doesn't seem to exist in 4.0.

In particular, he accesses the vertices like this:

```
Vector3[] a = new Vector3[myModelMeshPart.NumVertices];
myModelMesh.VertexBuffer.GetData<Vector3>(myModelMeshPart.StreamOffset + myModelMeshPart.BaseVertex * myModelMeshPart.VertexStride,
          a, 0, myModelMeshPart.NumVertices, myModelMeshPart.VertexStride);
```

but in XNA 4, `VertexBuffer` does not seem to be a property of `MeshModel`.

Can anyone please direct me to a basic iteration of a `Model`'s vertices?

Thank you.

@user2340634 Thank you for your response.
My attempt to use came up w/far less than actual # of verts.
I think I don't know how to use VertexBuffer.  Could you please comment on this code?

```
private void getVerts(Model mdl)
{
    foreach (ModelMesh mm in mdl.Meshes)
    {
        foreach (ModelMeshPart mp in mm.MeshParts)
        {
            VertexBuffer vb = mp.VertexBuffer;
            short[] s = new short[mp.PrimitiveCount * 3];
            IndexBuffer ib = mp.IndexBuffer;
            ib.GetData<short>(mp.StartIndex * 2, s, 0, mp.PrimitiveCount * 3);

            Vector3[] v = new Vector3[4];
            VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vert = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[4];
            mp.VertexBuffer.GetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(vert, 0, mp.NumVertices);
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            {
                v[i] = vert[i].Position;
                trace("(" + v[i].X.ToString() + ", " + v[i].Y.ToString() + ", " + v[i].Z.ToString() + ")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have a working sample that iterates thru verts, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
modModel = Content.Load<Model>("Cube1");
foreach (ModelMesh modmModel in modModel.Meshes)
{
    foreach (ModelMeshPart mmpModel in modmModel.MeshParts)
    {
        modelExtractor = new ModelExtractor(mmpModel, new Vector3[mmpModel.NumVertices * 2], new VertexPositionColor[mmpModel.NumVertices]);
        modelExtractor.ExtractVertices();
    }
}
for (int a = 0; a < modelExtractor.ArrVectors.Length; a++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(modelExtractor.ArrVectors[a]);
}
vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), modelExtractor.VpcVertices.Length, BufferUsage.None);
vertexBuffer.SetData(modelExtractor.VpcVertices);
```

This is from the main class. This is how I converted the Model into a ModelMeshPart. I didn't make a vertex buffer until after I extracted the data from the .fbx. The for loop (and the line of code inside of it) gives you a list of the extracted vertex data by writing it to the console window.

```
private ModelMeshPart mmpModel;
private Vector3[] arrVectors;
private VertexPositionColor[] vpcVertices;
```

These are the fields of my ModelExtractor class. They are used by the following method.

```
public void ExtractVertices()
{
    this.mmpModel.VertexBuffer.GetData<Vector3>(this.arrVectors);
    for (int a = 0; a < vpcVertices.Length; a += 2)
    {
        this.vpcVertices[a].Position.X = arrVectors[a].X;
        this.vpcVertices[a].Position.Y = arrVectors[a].Y;
        this.vpcVertices[a].Position.Z = arrVectors[a].Z;
    }
}
```

I extracted data of type "Vector3". Every vertex in the .fbx has a Vector3 for posistion and another for the normal. Only then do I move the position component by component from the array of Vector3s to an array of VertexPositionColors. Notice that the for loop increments "a" by 2 instead of 1. This is so that I can skip over the Vector3s for the normals.

Comment: Thank you, this let me get the vertices.  Too bad there isn't a corresponding buffer for the other data.

Comment: As if you really need a buffer for normal vectors. Buffers are really just for drawing.

Answer (score 2):

"Model" doesn't have "VertexBuffer". "ModelMesh" doesn't have "VertexBuffer" either. But, I found out that "ModelMeshPart" does indeed have "VertexBuffer". I'm doing data extraction from a .fbx for the first time as well. Any model we include in a project will have to be stored in a ModelMeshPart. That's not so bad. The whole mesh in the .fbx can be considered one part.

Comment: I need help with using that VertexBuffer.  The code sample I've patched together doesn't give me the vertices I can see in the fbx file.  I think it is my lack of skill with using VertexBuffer.  Do you have a basic iteration example you could show me?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (if the model has several parts you have to loop through them of course)

```
public static void ModelData(Model model)
{
    ModelMeshPart part = model.Meshes[0].MeshParts[0];

    VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[part.VertexBuffer.VertexCount];
    part.VertexBuffer.GetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(vertices);

    ushort[] drawOrder = new ushort[part.IndexBuffer.IndexCount];
    part.IndexBuffer.GetData<ushort>(drawOrder);

}
```